# How can I reuse the result of an expression variable in a lambda operator in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have this extension method to get the attribute of an Enum in c#.

```cs
public static TAttribute ToAttribute<TAttribute>(this Enum value)
            where TAttribute : Attribute => 
                value.GetType()
                    .GetField(Enum.GetName(value.GetType(), value))
                    .GetCustomAttributes(false)
                    .OfType<TAttribute>()
                    .SingleOrDefault();
```

As you can see i need to execute `value.GetType` two times (and this is not efficient). I also know I can remove the lambda expression and do it as the old times like:

```cs
        public static TAttribute ToAttribute<TAttribute>(this Enum value)
            where TAttribute : Attribute
        {
            var type = value.GetType();
            return type
                .GetField(Enum.GetName(type, value))
                .GetCustomAttributes(false)
                .OfType<TAttribute>()
                .SingleOrDefault();
        }
```

But is there any way to reuse the result of `value.getType` in one line expression like this ? maybe one keyword from c# that i'm not aware ?
I'm looking for something like this:

```cs
public static TAttribute ToAttribute<TAttribute>(this Enum value)
            where TAttribute : Attribute => 
                value.GetType()
                    .GetField(Enum.GetName(this, value))
                    .GetCustomAttributes(false)
                    .OfType<TAttribute>()
                    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Take a look here. This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397027/how-can-i-store-and-reuse-pieces-of-my-lambda-expressions/5397118#5397118

Comment: Short answer: no, impossible! If your concern relates to performance, it will not slow down your code. (performance difference is in nanoseconds)

Comment: Ok seems like there is no performance issues even executing the same code asynchronously millions of times. What about if the concern is code readability ?

Comment: or what about code quality ?

Comment: If the concern is about readability or quality, just use the second example.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, however second example will increase the total lines of codes and amount of code per line, i'm talking about optimization here. I asked this in case there is something there that i'm not aware, maybe something interesting if is not possible currently that can be developed in future versions of the language syntax in c# ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntax for reusing functions return value (except assigning variable of course). But if you want to avoid calling `GetType()` twice you can rewrite this particular expression like:

```
public static TAttribute ToAttribute<TAttribute>(this Enum value)
    where TAttribute : Attribute =>
        value.GetType()
             .GetField(value.ToString())
             .GetCustomAttributes(false)
             .OfType<TAttribute>()
             .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: `Enum.GetName(value.GetType(), value)` is the same as `value.ToString()` ?